Stack and Heap configuration in an IAR codebase
I have a group of embedded codebases written for the STR71 family of mircos that have been ported to IAR.
The latest one I am finding fails on the software update. The process involves copying a pre-built binary to RAM and then running it. However the porting process seems to have gone awry. Some of the local variables that are used to control this routine are being created in the same area of ram that we copy the loader file to. This means the variable is overwritten, and the copying process ends up going haywire.
    flashaddr = 0x00120000;               //start address in spi flash
    ramPointer = (char *) 0x20008000;         //start address in ram
    while (db < (0x00120000+fileSize)) 
    {
        *ramPointer = (char)flash_rbyte(flashaddr);      //copy from flash to ram
        ++ramPointer; ++flashaddr;                  //increment pointers

    }

As filesize is in the middle of the ram space I need, it gets altered, extending the while loop until much of the ram is overwritten.
Another codebase that will run another device controlled by the same design of controlboard is perfectly fine, the variables are earlier on in RAM.
I'm assuming there is some configuration difference between the two codebases, but I can't find it.

It is completely not unclear what you are asking about. What two codebases?

You'll have to start by comparing the linker script of your old environment compared to the one used in the IAR project. And if that doesn't help, compare map files.

ramPointer = (char *) 0x20008000 is btw an obvious bug as it should be (volatile char*) or ideally (volatile uint8_t*). How to access a hardware register from firmware?

Have you reserved space for the copied function in the linker configuration file? Otherwise the linker may decide to put variables and other non-constant data there.

..why is RAM content initialized by the firmware update? If you copied the updater inside RAM, just let it overwrite the flash memory, then execute a system reset (usually NVIC_SystemReset();, so that the startup code of the new binary can be executed normally.
